# How to index date field in lucene

Tags: java, date, lucene

I am new to lucene. I have to index date field.
i am using Following `IndexWriter` constructor in lucene 3.0.0.

```
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(FSDirectory.open(indexDir), new WhitespaceAnalyzer(), true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED)
```

my point is:
Why it needs a analyzer when date fields are not analyzed,while indexing I used `Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can store date field in this fashion..

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new Field("modified",
        DateTools.timeToString(f.lastModified(), DateTools.Resolution.MINUTE),
        Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
```

where f is a file object...

Now use the above document for indexwriter...

checkout the sample code comes with lucene... and the following link... 
http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_2_0/api/org/apache/lucene/document/DateTools.html

**UPDATE**

`Field.Index NOT_ANALYZED`

> Index the field's value without using
>   an Analyzer, so it can be searched. As
>   no analyzer is used the value will be
>   stored as a single term. This is
>   useful for unique Ids like product
>   numbers.

As per lucene javadoc you don't need analyzer for fields using `Field.Index NOT_ANALYZED` but i think by design the `IndexWriter` expects an analyzer as indexing the exact replica of data is not efficient in terms of storage and searching.

Comment: I  used same document u mentioned for indexing, but my point is why i need a analyzer in Indexwriter object while i am using Field.Index.Not_Analyzed

Comment: @Romi: please check the updated answer. Also, as a side advise, if you are thinking of just indexing a single field then using an embedded database like hsqldb or sqlite would be a much better option.